# How do I test burning tokens in my ICO contract?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, unittesting, mocha, chai

I'm writing tests for the burn func in ICO.sol

The first two tests are passing, but when I come to test where the tokens are indeed burned, the state of the ICO seems to change. To burn tokens, the ICO must have ended. So I start by checking the ICO state, and up to that point, the state is ended. When I call  `await ico.burn()` the state seems to change and I get the error below.

What could I be doing wrong?

##### error

```bash
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'Ico__StateShouldBeEnded()'
```

##### burn() func

```
    function burn() public onlyManager returns (bool) {
        icoState = getState();
        // require(icoState == State.afterEnd);
        if (icoState != State.afterEnd) {
            revert Ico__StateShouldBeEnded();
        }
        //burn
        balances[founder] = 0;
        return true;
    }
```

##### test file

```js
describe("burning tokens", () => {
              it("checks that the ico is ended before burning", async () => {
                  const icoState = await ico.getState()
                  assert.equal(icoState, 1) // state [1] = afterEnd on our ICO.sol
              })

              it("only allows manager to call", async () => {
                  const icoInvestor1connected = ico.connect(inverstor1)
                  await expect(icoInvestor1connected.burn()).to.be.rejectedWith("not owner")
              })

              it("should burn tokens", async () => {
                  const icoState = await ico.getState()
                  assert.equal(icoState, 1) // state [1] = afterEnd on our ICO.sol
                  
                  // up to this point the test passes. 
                  // it fails from the code below.

                  await ico.burn()
                  const founderBal = await ico.getFounderBalance()
                  assert.equal(founderBal.toString(), "0")
              })
          })
```

##### Repo

https://github.com/kihiuFrank/ICO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your contract on GitHub and you are running into an edge case for your contract.

In the test function you call `ico.getState()` which is a view function that reads the current state in the current block. Because this is a view function the block.timestamp will not increase and will be the same as what it was when you deployed the contract. Since `icoStart` is also set to be whatever the block timestamp was the contract was deployed, you have a state where `icoStart == block.timestamp`.

`getState()` does not test for equality so it falls to else statement returning `State.afterEnd`.

When you actually run the burn() function. This is a write transaction that increases the block number and hence the timestamp. Now the value of block.timestamp is icoStart++ so then `getState()` will return `State.running` which is why the burn() function reverts.

Your test should warp 3600 seconds for the test to pass since you are testing that the ICO is over.

```js
it("should burn tokens", async () => {
                  await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [3600])
                  const icoState = await ico.getState()
                  assert.equal(icoState, 1)
                  await ico.burn()
                  const founderBal = await ico.getFounderBalance()
                  assert.equal(founderBal.toString(), "0")
              })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solve it!
Should I and an else if on ```getState()``` or is it ok in your opinion? Something like;
```
else if (block.timestamp == icoStart) {
   return State.running;
}
```

Edit; I added and test it. I'll leave it there. Thanks again.

Comment: I noticed something. 
After adding the equality condition in the comment above, the state remains running even after increasing the block timestamp by 3600s. It doesn't respect this condition ```block.timestamp < icoEnd```

Comment: Yes because no block has been mined after you have increased the time. Because the `getState()` function is a view function, the value of block.timestamp will not change and will use the latest block (which was the deployment block) as it's value.

If you add a non view transaction after you increase the time. Something like


`await deployer.sendTransaction({to: ethers.constants.AddressZero})`

It will update the block.timestamp and the first assert will pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract is failing here, which is exactly what is intended to do:

```
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'Ico__StateShouldBeEnded()'
```

To test this error, you can do something like:

```
await expect(ico.burn()).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(contractName, "StateShouldBeEnded");
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It gave me a better way to write the first test. But the issue I was facing was testing that the founder token balance is updated to zero after burning.  When I call burn() the state seems to be running still. How do I change state to ended so it doesn't throw the ```Ico__StateShouldBeEnded()``` error?

Comment: If the transaction reverts, it won't make any change, the ico.burn function should succeed in order to have the balance updated